# What should be the sequence of commands in GIT for promoting an existing change file to the remote branch

Tags: devops

What should be the sequence of commands in GIT for promoting an existing change file to the remote branch

a) push, commit 
b) add, push, commit
c) commit, push
d) add, commit, push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d) add, commit, push
always prefer this.

OR

first of all clone the remote branch into local then make the appropriate Changes.